# apostrophe during Insert (Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am getting data though a PHP text box and inserting it into a MySQL database with a normal insert command. The text box takes in a comment frm the user for a particular Accession ID next to the text box. The problem is that when a user types in apostrophe (') for example the sentence "We have to take care of the PC's", an error is thrown.

I know why its happening because the SQL assumes it as the end of the string for that value but I don't know how to escape it. I would prefer escaping it in MYSQL.

If I escape it in MySQL can it still be exploited as SQL injection even if no error is generated and the insert works fine?

Comment: Use MySQLi Prepared Statements

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), or better yet, use parameterised queries with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: What do I do If I want to escape it in MySQL and not PHP.

Comment: @Ankur: You are escaping it for the context of the query. You can't escape it *in MySQL*, by that time, it's too late.

Comment: or Can I do Replace(''',' ') in MySQL. I don't really care if apostrophe's isn't there in the the string.

Comment: @Ankur No. It's a syntax issue. MySQL won't know where the string ends.

Answer (score 1):

use the function [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: What do I do If I want to escape it in MySQL and not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use **MySQLi prepared** statements.

You can pass special characters easily without any extra work.

Read [MySQLi prepared statements.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)