# MySQL: How to retrieve data that contain apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having a problem retrieving a data from mysql that has an apostrophe in it. I don't have problem in saving a data that has an apostrophe since that I am using `mysqli_real_escape_string` when inserting the data to the database but I get an error when retrieving it. My sample code in PHP for retrieving the data is `mysqli_query($con,"SELECT column1data FROM Table1 WHERE column2data LIKE '".$data."' ")or die(mysqli_error($con));` and the `$data` is the one that has an apostrophe in it.

Comment: Use parameters. It will make your life so much easier. Or escape the string as in insert. But rather parameters.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659879/mysql-php-with-special-characters-like-apostrophe-and-quotation-mark and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651170/apostrophe-during-insert-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) when binding variables, especially when it is a string, to your query. Not just for inserting data.

```
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($data);
```

You should also look at [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). No need to sanitize the variable before binding it your query, prepared statement will do it for you.

```
$data = "%{$data}%"; /* CHANGE THIS IF YOU DON'T WANT TO USE % */

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT column1data FROM Table1 WHERE column2data LIKE ?")){ /* PREPARE YOUR STATEMENT */
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $data); /* BIND THE DATA */
  $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
  $stmt->bind_result($column1data); /* BIND THE RESULT TO THIS VARIABLE */
  $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULT */
  echo $column1data; /* ECHO THE RESULT */
  $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE STATEMENT */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` **every** time that a string is being placed into your SQL code. Use `mysqli_real_escape_string($data)` rather than just `$data`.